# It is possible to set custom endpoint in aws-sdk npm module @aws-sdk-js

Tags: node.js, aws-sdk-js

I am trying to upload the file to the aws bucket which is in our Storage layer. All i need to do is set new endpoint while uploading, In java they use below method to set a custom endpoint, Do we have same thing in nodejs client or SDK as well ??

```
AWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey, secretKey);
AmazonS3 conn = new AmazonS3Client(credentials,clientConfig);
conn.setEndpoint("http://d4.domain.com:80");
```

Comment: In `@aws-sdk/client-s3` you are able to set this inside the S3Client constructor as "endpoint". Typescript makes this easier to identify. 

`const client = new S3Client({ endpoint: "http://localhost:9191" })`

Comment: @Luke this option only accepts Amazon AWS urls